# JLabel misplaced after adding JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I'm almost blind after reading lots of java swing articles, and still can not get panel to work.
When i add 2 JLabels, they are nicely aligned to left, with 5px padding defined by EmptyBorder, just as i want them to be.

[image]

I found that after adding ProgressBar with extra border for padding, does not work as expected, added 1 more panel, where i add ProgressBar. Progress looks good, but all my labels are displaced.
And finally it look like this (RED background is for debug, to see how JPanel draws):
[image]

**Question1:** How to fix this?
**Question2:** Is it standard approach for swing to place panel inside of other panel with other panels just to get formating i want?

Source:

```
public class AppInitProgressDialog {
    private static final int        VIEW_PADDING_VAL = 5;
    private static final Border     viewPaddingBorder = new EmptyBorder( VIEW_PADDING_VAL, VIEW_PADDING_VAL, VIEW_PADDING_VAL, VIEW_PADDING_VAL );

    private JPanel          view;   // Dialog view
    private JPanel          panel;

    private JPanel          progressPanel;

    private JLabel          title;
    private JLabel          progressDesc;
    private JProgressBar    progressBar;

    private void initPanel( int w, int h ) {
        view = new JPanel();
        view.setBorder( BorderFactory.createRaisedSoftBevelBorder() );
        view.setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        view.setSize( w, h );
        view.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder( viewPaddingBorder );
        panel.setLayout( new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS) );
        //panel.setLayout( new SpringLayout() );
        panel.setOpaque( false );

        JFrame parent = AppContext.getMe().getAppWindow().getFrame();
        int posx = (parent.getWidth() - w)/2;
        int posy = (parent.getHeight() - h)/2;
        view.add( panel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        view.setLocation( posx, posy );
    }

    private void initTitle() {
        title = new JLabel( "Progress title" );
        title.setAlignmentX( JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT );
        panel.add(title);
    }

    private void initProgress() {
        progressPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        progressPanel.setBackground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        progressPanel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder( 15, 30, 15, 30) );
        progressPanel.setBackground( Color.RED );

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 10000);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setAlignmentX( JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT );
        progressPanel.add(progressBar);

        panel.add( progressPanel );
        progressDesc = new JLabel( "Progress description" );
        panel.add(progressDesc);
    }

    public AppInitProgressDialog() {
        initPanel( 400, 100 );
        initTitle();
        initProgress();
    }

    public JComponent getView() {
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend editing the question and removing the Future Question 3. It is unrelated to your original question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `BorderLayout` for `panel`:

```
panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
...
panel.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
...
panel.add(progressPanel); // default CENTER
...
panel.add(progressDesc, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16837816/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");

    private void display() {
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new AppInitProgressDialog().getView());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    class AppInitProgressDialog {

        private static final int VIEW_PADDING_VAL = 5;
        private JPanel view;   // Dialog view
        private JPanel panel;
        private JPanel progressPanel;
        private JLabel title;
        private JLabel progressDesc;
        private JProgressBar progressBar;

        private void initPanel(int w, int h) {
            view = new JPanel();
            view.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
            view.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            view.setSize(w, h);
            view.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
            panel.setOpaque(false);

            view.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        private void initTitle() {
            title = new JLabel("Progress title");
            title.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            panel.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }

        private void initProgress() {
            progressPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            progressPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            progressPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(15, 30, 15, 30));
            progressPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

            progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 10000);
            progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
            progressBar.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            progressPanel.add(progressBar);

            panel.add(progressPanel);
            progressDesc = new JLabel("Progress description");
            panel.add(progressDesc, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        public AppInitProgressDialog() {
            initPanel(400, 100);
            initTitle();
            initProgress();
        }

        public JComponent getView() {
            return view;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Layout Managers rather than just adding panels to each other. Specifically in your case I think you can use **GridLayout**.

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,0,0));
```

Fore more details on layout refer to this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Comment: So sorry i can only mark one answer as correct, and after some trie out's Grid will work as well, but @trashgod answer sounds more like the way to do it. Hope 'up vote' will be eounf, as you some kind answered my second quesion, witch sounds like "Use layouts over panels". Thanks